# How can I adjuste the width of column in the Django Admin

Tags: python, django, django-admin

I'm try edit the width of my column in the django admin and let editable, but i don't know how to...

When I add this column "nome_short_oficina" in list_editable, show me an error:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LQwL8.png)

Could you help me?

For exemplo:

def nome_short_oficina(self):
return u"%s" % self.oficina
nome_short_oficina.short_description = _(u"Oficina")
nome_short_oficina.allow_tags = True 
I'm try edit the width of my column in the django admin and let editable, but i don't know how to...

When I add this column "nome_short_oficina" in list_editable, show me an error.